# Join Table vs Foreign Key/Ref

Tags: sql, database

Imagine I have two tables and they have a 1-to-Many relationship. Is it better to have a Join table storing the relationship, or issuing a foreign key in one of these tables? Take a look of these two situations:

```
Situation A:
Table 1: CreditCard
Table 2: Person
```

It seems to me quite making sense to put the creditCard_id as part of the Person table

```
Situation B:
Table 1: Order
Table 2: Person
```

This time I think I will put the order_id and person_id in a Join table?

Am I making a mistake in the above? Is there a standard/better way of determining this?

Comment: These examples are not 1to1 relations. A person can have more than one creditcard. And a person can have more than one order

Comment: Yeh you r right, very bad example. Modified my Q to 1 to Many, as teh problem is still the same. Thanks.

Comment: A "join table" would have a foreign key as well.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 to Many relation, people usually put the foreign key into the heavier table or the "Many" table.
So from your example, both go CreditCard and Order tables, by doing so you will remove duplicate data.

Imagine you which one is better:

- FK goes to the "Many" table

  Table People:
  ID    NAME
  1     A
  2     B

  Table CreditCard:
  ID    PEOPLE_ID
  1     1
  2     1
- FK goes to "1" table:
  Table People:
  ID    NAME    CreditCard_ID
  1     A       1
  1     A       2
  2     B       3

  Table CreditCard:
  ID
  1
  2
  3

Note: See how the ID and Name are repeated(ID=1, NAME=A) in the second example, that happens if you put the FK in the wrong table.

Comment: Hi, thx for the ans. So, you are suggesting not to use a Join table?

Comment: Not at all, if you mean by joining table is to create a table which saves both FK's. That's the right choice though for Many-to-Many relation.

Answer (score 0):

I would make three tables; a person table with all their info( name, address, etc. ), a credit card table with all the info( expiration date, security number?, etc.. ) then another table connecting them with the PersonID and CreditCardID.  But what do I know, I'm still in school lol so wait for someone else to answer you.

Comment: Still being in school might mean that that you haven't developed any bad habits yet.  Having said that, you are describing a many to many relationship.  It is only valid if a person can have more than one card, which is probably true, and if a card can have more than one person, which might not be true.